# Can't convert Type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody' en 'UnityEngine.GameObject and no definition for Addforce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm running with two issues on my script in Unity one with getting my Rigidbody and one to apply some force to my ball.

For the Rigidbody [26,23] *Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject' [Assembly-CSharp]*

For the Addforce [52,24]
*'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'Addforce' and no accessible extension method 'Addforce' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' was found (is a using directive or assembly reference missing ?) [Assembly-CSharp]*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StrokeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    GameObject playerBallRB;

    bool doRoll = false;

    private void FindPlayerBall() 
    {
       GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

       if(go == null)
       {
           Debug.LogError("Ball not found. ");
       }

       playerBallRB = go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

   // Update is called once per visual frame Input

    private void Update() 
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))  
      {
            doRoll = true;

      }

    }

   // FixedUpdate runs on every tick of the physics engine, Manipulation
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(doRoll)
        {
          // Ball roll
          doRoll = false;

          Vector3 forceVec = new Vector3(0, 0, 10f);

          playerBallRB.Addforce(forceVec, ForceMode.Impulse);

        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags. This has nothing to do with `Visual-Studio` and note that `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like language used in previous Unity versions and is long deprecated by now. Besides that I would close this as typo-based .. the error is pretty clear ;) Your field `playerBallRB` should rather be a `Rigidbody` not a `GameObject` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a rigidbody to your gameobject.

As for your code, you need to have an rigidBody to your playerBall attached.
Then, you need to change your code so that it grabs your rigidbody instead of just your gameobject:

```
      playerBallRB.gameObject.rigidbody = go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
      playerBallRB.gameObject.rigidbody.Addforce(forceVec, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: Thank you I dumb I forget to set the Rigidbody 

I had that for the begging

```GameObject playerBallRB;```

This fix everything 

 ```Rigidbody playerBallRB;```

thank you

Comment: Make sure to accept my answer as correct and upvote it. You're welcome!